# ERROR: malformed array literal: "[{...}]" DETAIL: "[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions

Tags: sql, postgresql

To extract text of `insert` (`{"ops":[{"insert":"just a plain text.\n"},{"insert":"2nd line"}]}`) I created this function:

```
create or replace function _json_extract_text
(
    j json
)
returns text
language 'plpgsql'
as $$
declare vjay json[];
declare txt text := '';
declare i json;
begin
    select (j::json->>'ops')::json into vjay;
    FOREACH i IN ARRAY vjay
    LOOP 
        txt := txt || (select i::json->>'insert') || ' ';
    END LOOP;
    return txt;
end;
$$;
```

`select _json_extract_text('{"ops":[{"insert":"just a plain text.\n"},{"insert":"2nd line"}]}'::json)` received:

> ERROR:  malformed array literal: "[{"insert":"just a plain text.\n"},{"insert":"2nd line"}]"

> DETAIL:  "[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions.

> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function current._json_extract_text(json) line 6 at
> SQL statement SQL state: 22P02

UPDATE: Thanks to @Bergi, it's working as

```
...
AS $BODY$
begin
  return string_agg(obj->>'insert' || ' ', '')
  FROM json_array_elements(j->'ops') obj;
end;
$BODY$;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`json[]` is almost always a mistake. You don't have a postgres array of json values. Also you shouldn't use `j::json->>'ops'` if you don't want to get back `text`.

To iterate a JSON array is postgres, use [`json_array_elements`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE).

And instead of an iterative loop in a procedural function, just use the [`string_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-aggregate.html) aggregate function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION _json_extract_text(j json) RETURNS text
IMMUTABLE
RETURN (
  SELECT string_agg(obj->>'insert' || ' ', '')
  FROM json_array_elements(j->'ops') obj
);
```

Comment: `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "RETURN" LINE 3: RETURN (`. Some elements have  `{"insert":{"image":"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJ..."}},` or `"video": "https://www.youtube.com/..."`, possible to skip them? Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I've used Postgres 14 syntax. Use `LANGUAGE SQL AS $…$` for older versions

Comment: Works as charm, thank you!